# How to redirect all pages in a subdirectory to one particular page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

A while back I redid a website in Wordpress. I did not notice that there was a subdirectory called /dalimduo/ within the root, which still has pages showing up in Google search results.

Example of this sub-directory's urls:

- http://www.blanchardsystems.com/dalimduo/index.html
- http://www.blanchardsystems.com/dalimduo/about.html

I would like to redirect any page within /dalimduo/ to this page: http://www.blanchardsystems.com/event/duo-2015-in-new-orleans/

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/dalimduo/ http://www.blanchardsystems.com/event/duo-2015-in-new-orleans/
```

or if you're already using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^dalimduo/ http://www.blanchardsystems.com/event/duo-2015-in-new-orleans/ [L,R=301]
```